# Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength still gives exception

Tags: java, ssl, cryptography, java-7

```
  error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentExeption: Cannot support 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA with currently installed providers at 
sun.security.ssl.CipherSuiteList.(Unknown Source) at 
sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.setEnabledCipherSuites(Unknown Source)
```

I've already installed Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 7 and it still gives the same error. Can someone please help?

Comment: i'm guessing that you didn't install it successfully.  maybe you are testing a different java install than the one you updated?  maybe the permissions weren't correct during the update?

Comment: It's certainly available in my (old) Java version: 1.7.0_21... What JRE are you using? Could you run `System.out.printf("Version: %f", Security.getProvider("SunJSSE").getVersion());` ?

Comment: @owlstead Version: 1,600000

Comment: @jtahlborn I was careful to choose the right version. and checked the permissions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running Java 6 and you installed the unlimited strength stuff for Java 7.

Install the correct version.

Comment: after I read that comment i tried and the same error appeared

Comment: Yes, but you are assuming Java 7, and you are getting a version for Java 6, so you are double likely to be in the wrong folder.

Comment: @user3338486 My answer is based on the evidence in what you posted.